# Using build_command with CruiseControl.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.rb

I'm using cruisecontrol.rb for continuous integration, and have the following settings in cruise_config.rb.

```
Project.configure do |project|
  ...
  project.build_command = 'my_build_script.sh'
  ...
end
```

I've tried to follow this [blog post](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mbarinek/blog/articles/1450-rails-3-with-rvm-and-cruise-control).

However, I can't get 'my_build_script.sh' to run.  It kicks off by running 'bundle install'. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused--do you still have a question, or are you satified with commenting out the above code as per your update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cruise allows you disable the automatic `bundle install`, via `project.use_bundler = false`.

See the [feature announcement](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.cruise-control.devel/288).

It's a shame that the default is true, making `bundle install` behave strangely with rvm gemsets. They should've made the feature opt-in instead of automatic, seeing that a lot of people use rvm gemsets.

Apparently cruise will use the same `GEM_HOME` as the parent cruise process is using. If you're running cruise under Phusion Passenger, it'll use the `GEM_HOME` where the passenger gem is installed (I'm not sure if this is still a problem with passenger 4 though).

Answer (score 2):

In cruisecontrol.rb in app/models/build.rb:42

```
if @project.uses_bundler?
 execute self.bundle_install, :stdout => build_log_path, :stderr => build_log_path, :env => project.environment
end
```

It is hard coded to run bundler first if it detects a Gemfile, I commented this out and did it manually after the rvm gemset was set and it worked.

Here is a forked version (massive ui changes though) https://github.com/timoxley/cruisecontrol.rb

Comment: Cruise allows you disable the automatic `bundle install`, via `project.use_bundler = false`. See [original announcement](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.cruise-control.devel/288)